# jquery/PHP: getting NULL return from curl string

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, curl

I'm seeing some peculiar behavior with sending a JSON string back from PHP to Jquery's $.ajax function.

when I visit my php script from a browser or from calling it via command line with php, it returns completely valid JSON (tested with jsonlint.com). However, when I make an AJAX call from my HTML file I always get NULL back.

Basically from PHP I'm doing this:

```
// case in a switch that handles command 'getinfo':
$url = "http://someapi.com:1234/api/entity/" . $tagid;
$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:pass" );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );

$reply = curl_exec( $ch );

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $reply;
```

This spits out this:

```
[ {
  "class" : "entity",
  "guid" : "IT_EQUIPMENT_abcdef12345677890",
  "retired" : false,
  "deletable" : true,
  "$aAssetTamper" : false
} ]
```

I've tried both with and without RETURNTRANSFER set, and also with and without the header() line. On the HTML side, I am calling with Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "gimmedata.php",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    data: { 'cmd' : 'getinfo', 'tagid' : $('#tag').val },
    success: function( data, textStatus ) {
        // rfcode location
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

The status always returns "success", and the data is always "[]".

Weird thing is, if I copy the output from the PHP script and then paste it back into the script itself, then echo that string without going through curl, then my AJAX call works fine:

```
echo '
[ {
  "class" : "entity" 
  "guid" : "IT_EQUIPMENT_abcdef12345677890",
  "retired" : false,
  "deletable" : true,
  "$aAssetTamper" : false
} ]';
return;

$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:pass" );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );

$reply = curl_exec( $ch );

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $reply;
```

I have no idea what it can be. Any clue? Is curl_exec doing weird things to the text?

Comment: Are you sure it's returning valid JSON, and did you try a json_encode to see if that changes anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data passing from JavaScript is wrong:

```
data: { 'cmd' : 'getinfo', 'tagid' : $('#tag').val },
```

You should use `.val` as a function, not as a property:

```
data: { 'cmd' : 'getinfo', 'tagid' : $('#tag').val() },
```

Answer (score 0):

php has a nifty function: json_encode.  perhaps you can see if integrating that  into your code might help ensure the validity of your json?   http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Secondly, you're request is synchronous, which is generally not the best thing to use unless you have to, theres a lot out there on that topic

also try adjusting your ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "gimmedata.php",
    async: false,
    data: { 'cmd' : 'getinfo', 'tagid' : $('#tag').val() },
    success: function( data, textStatus ) {
        // rfcode location
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

also, can you post some more info  on how your PHP code is receiving te ajax request?  I'd expect to see $_POST in there somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone happens upon this post I too ran into this issue...

In my case the variable I was using to do the curl request were not being properly assigned.  So when I was testing my php curl with hard coded information it was echoing the proper JSON responses.  But when I ran it through an JQuery Ajax call it was comming back with null as the JSON data.  I scratched my head for a while and tried a bunch of things thinking curl may be appending some bad data from the response.  But low and behold when I finally got frustrated enough to check that my key curl request parameters were actually being correctly identified before the request was made.. well they were not.

Always check to make sure you incoming GET / POST variables are being correctly assigned!